# Using a specified font in textgreek

Tags: unicode, greek, computer-modern

I am trying to use Computer Modern Bright in greek text. The [otf version](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/cm-unicode/fonts/otf/cmunbmr.otf) of the font has specific upright characters for greek that can be used in other applications, so I am assuming the afm/pfb fonts do as well.

The `textgreek` package seems to be able to do this, but the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/textgreek/textgreek.pdf) (section 2.1) says that it can only use 3 fonts, which I assume is not the case as many other fonts have greek coverage.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{cmbright}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03BF}{\textomikron}

\begin{document}

    English text in Computer Modern Bright

    Έλληνες κείμενο in cbgreek

    \textgreek{'Ellhnes ke'imeno} in cbgreek

\end{document}
```

Rendered using regular LaTeX:

[image: rendered pdf]

Rendered as desired using XeLaTeX / LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Bright}

\begin{document}

    English text in CMU Bright

    Έλληνες κείμενο in CMU Bright

\end{document}
```

[image]

What am I missing? Where should I look? Is the issue with the `textgreek` package or with LaTeX itself?

## Addendum

I got it working using the more modern LaTeX engines, but still the issue remains for users who for some reason are limited to the standard. Surely there must be a way to do this also for them?

Comment: I don't know from where the authors of the cm-unicode fonts took the Greek version for CM Bright. But you can certainly use those fonts in XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX with `fontspec`.

Comment: Why would you assume that the people responsible for `textgreek` are wrong about what `textgreek` does? Isn't the more natural assumption to think that they *do* know - in the absence, obviously, of evidence to the contrary?

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably misunderstand what `textgreek` does and/or what is required to support fonts in (pdf)TeX. The package will not work with arbitrary fonts ***even if those fonts provide the required characters***. So whether the type1 versions of CM Bright include the characters you need is, strictly speaking, irrelevant. (But if they included them, you could add support for them, of course, without needing to create the characters first.)

`textgreek` provides support for specific fonts and only those specific fonts are supported by the package. This is why the authors say the package supports 3 fonts - if zillions of fonts provide upright Greek, `textgreek` still only supports 3 of them.

To see why, we can peek inside `textgreek.sty`. Here's the crucial command:

```
\newcommand*{\textgreekfont}{%
  \fontencoding{LGR}%
  \edef\textgreek@fontmap{\textgreekfontmap}%
  \expandafter\textgreek@findfont\textgreek@fontmap\textgreek@eof%
  \selectfont%
}%
```

So we can see that this is using `\textgreekfontmap`. Let's look for that:

```
\DeclareOption{cbgreek}{%
\renewcommand*{\textgreekfontmap}{%
  {eur/*/*}{U/eur/*/*}
  {phv/*/*}{U/psy/*/*}}}%
\DeclareOption{euler}{%
\renewcommand*{\textgreekfontmap}{%
  {phv/*/*}{U/psy/*/*}
  {*/bx/n}{U/eur/b/n}
  {*/b/n}{U/eur/b/n}
  {*/*/n}{U/eur/m/n}
  {*/*/it}{OML/*/*/*}}}%
\DeclareOption{artemisia}{%
\renewcommand*{\textgreekfontmap}{%
  {eur/*/*}{U/eur/*/*}
  {phv/*/*}{U/psy/*/*}
  {*/b/n}{LGR/artemisia/b/n}
  {*/bx/n}{LGR/artemisia/bx/n}
  {*/*/n}{LGR/artemisia/m/n}
  {*/b/it}{LGR/artemisia/b/it}
  {*/bx/it}{LGR/artemisia/bx/it}
  {*/*/it}{LGR/artemisia/m/it}
  {*/b/sl}{LGR/artemisia/b/sl}
  {*/bx/sl}{LGR/artemisia/bx/sl}
  {*/*/sl}{LGR/artemisia/m/sl}
  {*/*/sc}{LGR/artemisia/m/sc}
  {*/*/sco}{LGR/artemisia/m/sco}}}%
\newcommand*{\textgreekfontmap}{}%
```

What this shows is that `\textgreekfontmap` is defined in one of 3 specific ways, depending on the option chosen (either explicitly or as the package default).

Note that the structure of the definition is font-specific: the definitions are tailored to the 3 fonts which the package supports.

Hence, it is clear that the package is not supporting arbitrary fonts with upright Greek characters, even if those fonts are otherwise supported by TeX.

So the authors of the package do seem to know whereof they speak when they say that their package supports 3 fonts.

Comment: So by editing that style file, one could add support for other fonts? How would one know what data to add?

Comment: @svenper You shouldn't edit the file itself. You could make a copy and rename it. As to what the data should be, it depends on the font. You have to look at the font and, specifically, at the TeX/LaTeX support files for the font. (Unless you are also going to create those files, in which case, you create them first.) There's no general rule here. It just depends on the font, the package, maybe the decisions you make about how to implement support.